# Does Qt WebView support webpage containing asynchronous Ajax?

Tags: javascript, qt, asynchronous, qwebview

I use Chrome browser to load the webpage, it works fine (the position of dot is always changing when I change some JSON file). But when I use Qt `WebView`, it cannot change position of the dot while I change the JSON file, even the reload method doesn't work.

I use ECharts (some chart class library) to update the position of dot. The update method uses the feature of ECharts supporting asynchronous loading. I also use `setTimeInterval` method to make sure the webpage can get the new position of the dot according to some JSON file per sec.

Comment: What do you mean by JSON file? What is your Qt version? Why don't you use `QWebEngineView` instead of `QWebView`? What is the position of the dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, and moreover, it is the only way to work with external resources (like Ajax). It is said in the documentation of [QWebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) (if you are using a version of Qt prior to 5.4) and in the documentation of [QWebEngineView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) (all the other cases).

> ... whereas external objects are loaded asynchronously.

`external objects` refer to things such as JavaScript programs or style sheets (CSS). Be careful though :

> The HTML document is loaded immediately.